# DataSource.getConnection is very slow on Linux but not using windows

Tags: java, mysql, linux, tomcat

Im developing some web services using Java and axis2 framework. This application is supposed to run under tomcat 5.5 on ubuntu 8.04 so I have a testserver setup with those versions.

When I develop locally on my windows machine getting a response from a web service call takes about 50 MS. If I deploy the same application on a Linux machine (I have tried both the ubuntu machine and a machine running arch linux), the first web service call takes about 20 seconds to make.

I have done some trouble shooting and come to the conclution that my `DataSource.getConnection` call takes about 9 seconds the first time and about 5 seconds each after that. If I enable connection pooling it will ofcourse speed up my calls after the first call (since the connection is saved) and calls after that will also take 50MS which is good, but im hoping that there is a more robust solution then to increase the amount of connection pools. What is really bothering me is that this works great on my windows machine, but problems arrise using Linux.

Could anyone point me to a direction about what could be the problem? I have no errors in my tomcat log.

Using Ubuntu 8.04
MySql 5.0.83
Tomcat 5.5.27
Java 6
Axis2 1.2 (also tried 1.6)

Comment: Did you check your network profiles? Are the Linux, Windows, Database boxes in the same network (routing, firewalls, latency, etc.)? To me this sounds like a network issue...

Comment: When using the command line MySQL client what are the connection times like? The connection time is dependent on how long the server takes to respond.

Comment: The Linux, Windows and Database are on different machines but in the same network. Conneting using mysql -h takes about 5 seconds

Comment: I know with Oracle if you set `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` it will speed it up, as well as Tomcat. See http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp on the Entropy Source section.